# How to make a Google Maps marker a simple URL link?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm looking for a way to make a Google Map marker a simple link (`<a href="">`).

I **don't** want to reproduce a link behavior with Javascript (`location.href` for example) because I want the user to be able to open the link in a new Tab or Window (using the middle click for example).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a **workaround** for this problem.

1. **Wrap the google map div with a link** [with href="#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used)
2. Set [mouseouver and mouseout events of the markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) to **update the link href** (mouseover sets the link to the page corresponding to the marker, mouseout sets it back to "#").

This way, middle click / ctrl click / normal left mouse button click all have the **desired classic behaviors**, and the overhead is very limited.

This solution works for a fullscreen map, because following the "#" href will not have any effect. If you want this solution to work on a **page that is more than -one screen height- high**, you should also add an click event listener on the link to [block the event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event) when the href is set to "#".

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. Only solution that comes to my mind would be to use jquery to wrap each marker element into `<a href="..." />`:

```
$(something).wrap('<a href="..." />');
```

The problem is how to find all markers, i.e. what would be that expression "something".

Comment: @skarE, not always - if they are draggable, they are as separate markup.

Answer (score 0):

Because a click on a marker is a javascript event you can only use location.href/window.open functions.

If you want standard html links then your best option is to open a infowindow when the user clicks on a marker and have the content of infowindow be a html link.