# How to redirect a html page to two other html pages using two buttons?

Tags: html, redirect, button, click

I can connect to another html page by using the following code by using a button click.

```
<form action="where-you-want-to-go"><input type="submit"></form>
```

but I have a problem. When there are two buttons on the page how can I redirect them to two different pages by using this code? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: use href, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used

Answer (score 7):

YOU COULD DO something like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location = 'where-you-want-to-go';">
<input type="button" onclick="window.location = 'where-you-want-to-go';">
```

Comment: @AnaMaria I don't intend to offend you in anyway, but from my perspective persuading the OP for upvotes is impolite. So just a friendly suggestion :)

Comment: @JeslyVarghese, i did not persuade the OP for anything. I only told him that he can mark either my soloution as answer or any other. I just added that he/she should also consider marking +1 to everyone who tried to help. Nothing wrong in that. Helps everyone

Comment: :) , you can see here fun comments!!! @AnaMaria and Jeslu Varghese ,after read your comments , i can imagine your faces ;),BTW thanks AnaMaria

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "redirect"? After clicking submit button the form data is send to action url. If you want you can create two forms:

```
<form action="action-first"><input type="submit"></form>
<form action="action-second"><input type="submit"></form>
```

But if you don't want to send data, you can use links to go to the page:

```
<a href="/action-first">First link</a>
<a href="/action-second">Second link</a>
```

Comment: I got the point now. I had some misunderstanding about the <form> tag...I got the whole point. Its a good explaination.