# Using 'href="#"' needs 2 Back presses in some browsers

Tags: javascript, href

I have javascript that uses 'href="#"' to call a function when it's clicked.  The problem is that when I run it on Chrome, I need 2 Back presses to return to the referrer page, but on Opera, I only need 1 Back press.

I read the details about using 'href="#"' here: 
   [What is href="#" and why is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used)

here is my test code:

```
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testOnClick(){
            document.write("onClick() support was detected!<br>");
        }
    </script>
</p>

Clicking on the link should clear the screen and display progress text<br />
<a  onclick="testOnClick();" href="#!">
    Click here to test onClick
</a>
```

Comment: links with dashes create a new entry in history. first backpress takes you to the same page without hash, and second takes you to previous page.

Comment: Why the specify `href` at all? Do you actually need that behavior? You can style your `<a>` so that it has `cursor:pointer` and `text-decoration:underline`.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault);

```
function testOnClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.write("onClick() support was detected!<br>");
}
```

It prevents your navigator to navigate to the # link, thus, having to press back.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get similar functionality by using a different element and making it look like a link.  If you aren't navigating the user to a different section of the page or a new page, for example, you probably should be using the `<a>` tag.

Here's a fiddle for what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/2ph2d2gd/

The use case for this would be to open a modal, or do some other action that doesn't necessarily navigate the user anywhere.  I don't know your specific circumstances, so you may or may not want to use something like this.

Note: I used `alert` instead of `document.write` because jsfiddle doesn't allow the latter.

HTML:

```
Clicking on the link should clear the screen and display progress text<br />
<span class="link" onclick="testOnClick();">
    Click here to test onClick
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.link{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function testOnClick(){
    alert("onClick() support was detected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results leaving the href blank in this scenario. It doesn't reload the page with "#" at the end of the URL and events still fire.

I'm not sure how well that works with JS onclick, but you could replace that with jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#link").on("click", function() {
            alert("click");
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="link" href="">
    Click here to test onClick
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `href="#"`, make sure `onclick` always contains `return false`; at the end, that any called function does not throw an error and if you attach a function dynamically to the `onclick` property make sure that as well as not throwing an error it returns `false`.

OR

Use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

More information about why can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)