# bootstrap 3 dropbox can not work when assign href to <a> item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In following example, dropdown menu works.
It will fail when we rename the bug2 to bug(same as href in <a>), check it in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jeqarateqije/1/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#bug" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bug2">main</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**SOLVED**

For keep same style, the corrected version is replace this line

```
<a href="#bug" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

with

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown link will work no matter what you have listed as the `href=` as long as that is not pointing to an existing `id` on the page.

So for example all of these work and the user will have the same experience whether `href="#"`, `href="#blah"`, or `href="#hello`.  This is because neither `blah` nor `hello` is an id that is in use on the page.

The id `bug` is being used on the page.  When you introduce the `href="#bug"` it is pointing to the `<div id="bug">main</div>`, and nothing happens because that is simply a plain text div.

Comment: I think `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"` should change to `<a  class="dropdown-toggle"` in the first example in http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar.  And more, why here use `<a` if `href` is useless here.

Comment: Because you want the element to be styled like a link.  Also you can read more about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used.  I guess you could simply eleminate the `href="#"` altogether though.