# AngularJS tag not coming up as link

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS. I have created a basic website where I have added 2 links and I want to create route for the same.
Below is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="links">
    <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
   <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
</div>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run my code, both tags above are not coming as links.

Comment: `both tags above are not coming as links` what are they coming as?

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/H614Q7v2NDO3q7qsRU5i?p=preview

Comment: Did my answer help you? Is there something still not working for you regarding this subject?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is simply that you don't have any routes registered with ui-router. When you register your routes, the `ui-sref` directive will add the href tags and the default hyperlink styling will be applied. Read more about hyperlinks and anchor tags [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used/21397285#21397285).

### Example: [**Live Demo**](http://jsbin.com/dovito/1/edit)

```
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('myState', {
      url: '/my/path',
      controller: 'MyStateController',
      templateUrl: 'my-state.html'
    });

  }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="myState">My State</a>
```

The `ui-sref` directive will then render this:

```
<a href="/my/path">My State</a> <!-- HTML5 Mode -->
<a href="#/my/path">My State</a> <!-- hashbang mode -->
```