# Empty Link Leading to Top of Page

Tags: html

In the navigation bar of a website I'm working on, I have the following code:

`<a href="#">Menu</a>`

For some reason, clicking on then 'Menu' link jumps me back to the top of the page. I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Is there any javascript to go along with this? Are you curious as to why this happens in the context of your menu item or why a '#' href jumps you to the top of the page at all?

Comment: Because it refreshes the page and ads a slash to your url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` used in `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag specifies the id of an HTML element to where the page needs to scroll to.

i.e., clicking on the link `<a href="#abc">Goto abc</a>` will scroll the page to display the HTML element with `id="abc"` on top.

So, when we give `#` only (no `id` specified), it will take us to the top of the page.

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/05peuxq9/2/)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used) also

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

`<a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu</a>`

Comment: Offering some reasoning as to why one should use this code snippet is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` specifies an anchor. You can name an `<a>` tag (the "a" stands for "anchor"), and then you can use a link like `#section1` to jump to the `a` tag named "section1".

Because you didn't specify an anchor to jump to, it goes to the top of the page.

You can use this to link to parts of other pages as well. The link `<a href="anotherpage.htm#someSectionOfAnotherPage"` will link to the `a` tag named `someSectionOfAnotherPage` on the page `anotherPage.htm`.