# How can I prevent my hyperlink from refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

everyone, I'm using a javascript to do a form popup on a page.  The form is included rather than being directly a part of the page.

When I click on hyperlink the form only shows for a second then disappears.  It works if I literally create the form in the same page instead of including it as a php file.

I believe it's the hyperlink that's refreshing the page.
How can I prevent my hyperlink from refreshing the page?

```
<?php < scripttype = "text/javascript" >
function deselect(e)
    {
    $('.popUp') . slideFadeToggle(
   function ()
    {
    e . removeClass('selected');
    });
}

$(
function ()
{
$('#edit') . on('click',
function ()
    {
    if ($(this) . hasClass('selected'))
        {
        deselect($(this));
        }
      else
        {
        $(this) . addClass('selected');
        $('.pop') . slideFadeToggle();
        }

    return false;
    });
$('.close') . on('click',
function ()
    {
    deselect($('#edit'));
    return false;
    });
});
$ . fn . slideFadeToggle =
function (easing, callback)
{
return this . animate(
    {
    opacity:
        'toggle', height:
            'toggle'
            }

        , 'fast', easing, callback);
        };
</script>
```

Here's the form that is in a seperate file...

```
<div id="contactInfoDiv" class="fluid popUp">
<form id="updateForm" method="post" action="editContact.php">
<pre>
First Name:   <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo    $firstname;?>"><br>
    Last Name:    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo  $lastname;?>"><br>
    Address:      <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address;?>"><br>
    Phone:        <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"><br>
    Email:        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"><br>
</pre>
</form>
    </div>
```

Edit

What I'm trying to do is just include the above form like this:

```
<?php include("editContact.php");

<a href="userProfile.php" id="edit">Edit</a>
```

UPDATE:

I added e.preventDefault() like the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function deselect(e) {

  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
 e.removeClass('selected');

    });
   e.preventDefault();
 }

   $(function() {
   $('#edit').on('click', function() {
 if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
  deselect($(this));               
} else {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
}
 return false;
 });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
  deselect($('#edit'));
   return false;
   });
});

 $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing,      callback);
 };
```

Comment: You should take a look into using ajax to make the call to editcontact.php which will help you display the form in place without a refresh as well.

Comment: try something like this on your anchor. `<a id='edit' href='#' onclick='return false;'>` It will fire the javascript just fine but will not return its original function, which is to link to something.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent a link's default behavior with jQuery, you can start your function with:

```
$("#edit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Tried the e.preventDefault() with no different result.  Sorry MrTechie, I'm not  to confident with ajax to make it work.

Comment: You added the preventDefault at the wrong place @CloudyKooper, the parameter `e` should be the `click` event, not your jquery object

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the structure of your HTML Link.

```
<?php include("editContact.php");

<a href="#edit" id="edit">Test</a>
```

The href='#edit' makes the link try to make your browser focus the  element whose id='edit', instead of trying to load a remote page for you. Now the user won't leave your page (no http request, no refresh), and the jquery event still gets triggered.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used) for more information.

(thanks to DarkBee in the comments).

Comment: Using an `#` as link will send the browser back to top. It does not prevent the initial event from firing up!

Comment: In that case you should try using a tag, such as href='#something' probably right next to the link so it doesn't make the user "go away", where 'something' is the id of the pop up you're opening.

Comment: As OP is using jquery, jackel's answer is the one that is 100% correct

Comment: That's just subjective thinking, getting the job done using a different approach. But thanks for the sweet yet not very reasonable downvote.