# Spring-boot configuration

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, yeoman-generator

I am trying to use a yeoman angular generator inside a Spring-boot application. I have the following project structure

```
/project
 -/src/main
 -- /java
 -- / resources
 --- /application.properties
 --- /public
  ---- /app
  ----- /index.html
  ----- /bower-components
  ----- /scripts
  ----- /views/**.html
  ----- /images
  ----- /styles
```

My goal is when the application loads up, index.html page would load from /project/src/main/resources/public/app/index.html and the URL should be "localhost:8080/#/". Currently, the URL looks like this localhost:8080/app/index.html.

I tried to put the mapping in application.properties as :

```
server.context-path=/public/app
```

I also tried to overwrite the Application configuration by extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. The class is :

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/public/" };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {        
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "app/index" ); 
    }
}
```

But looks like this isn't working either. Can anyone comment on what am I missing and how to achieve the URL as "locahost:8080/#/" even if the index.html is located at /src/main/resources/public/app.

Note: If I keep my index.html page at /src/main/resources/public, the URL is shown as desired [locahost:8080/#/] . Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not sure if it is correct to access to your application's index page via `localhost:8080/#/`. As '#' is used to navigation on current page. Take a look at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397285/548601) answer about hyperlinks.

**Edited:**

Looks like your problem in CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS. Have you tried to change `"classpath:/resources/"` to `"classpath:/resources/app/"`?

Otherwise, you can move your html files from resources folder to WEB-INF and add the configuration of `InternalResourceViewResolver` to your `@ApplicationConfiguration` class, set it as following:

```
@Bean 
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/app/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work. But I found a solution to it which I found out.  Please see below

Answer (score 0):

In my application configuration, I added the app folder

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/public/app/" };

@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
```

Then added the method addViewControllers as :

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) { 
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html") ;
    }
```

No change in my folder structure (as mentioned the question) was required.

Hope this helps others as well.