# How to dynamically change the id of a text element inside iterate logic in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts

Here is the code I used:

```
<% int  number=0 %>  
<logic:iterate name="sample" id="sample1" property="lstWaferRequests" indexId="rowid"> 
<tr>
     <% number= (rowid.intValue())+1;%> 
<td>
    <html-el:text name="sample1" property="strExpDate" styleId='<%="Date"+number%>'/>   
</td>

<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("<%="Date"+number%>");
</script>

<a href="javascript:show_calendar(x,'');">
    <img src="images/calendar.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

I tried to increment a variable(number) and add it to the id of `sample1 textbox`but the id is not changing for the next iteration. I checked it using the `Inspect Element option in IE11`.

I used `setatttribute()` method in javascript to set ID but I got an error that,

> object does not support setattribute method.

*I need to change the ID of the text box which stores the date value(sample1) dynamically* since I need to pass it as an argument to `show_calendar` method.

Please advise.

Comment: use $('your element').attr("id","assign ID");

Comment: Can you post your `show_calendar` function as well?

Comment: Thank You :) I will try that but is there a way to  change  the  argument which is been passed to the JavaScript method dynamically??

Comment: I found the calendar script in this URL http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/timestamp.shtml?

Comment: So you want to pass `name of element` and `value` in `show_calendar`?

Answer (score 0):

I have added class to your `textbox` and `anchortag`.

From your link, I get to know that you have to pass the `name` attribute of textbox not `id`.

Hence I added dynamic names. This you can achieve by `strExpDate<%=number%>`. But I recommend using `JSTL` instead of scriptlets. 
See `java expert` [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) post [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?) for details.

**Update :**
In your logic iterate, you have to change like this

```
<% int number=1 %>  
<logic:iterate name="sample" id="sample1" property="lstWaferRequests" > 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <html-el:text name="strExpDate<%=number%>" property="strExpDate" styleClass="dates" />   
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="test" href="#">
                <img src="images/calendar.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <% number++; %>
</logic:iterate>
```

In your script find the clicked anchor tag and nearest textbox with class `dates`. I used `jQuery` library, since you tagged it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").click(function(e) {
        var value = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('.dates').val();
        var name = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('.dates').attr('name');
        alert("Name : "+name+" Value : "+value);

        // You can call show_calendar() from here by passing name and value.
    });
});
```

See the [**Demo in fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/m6grjat4/4/). Let me know if any clarification, Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this :) But I am not predefining the number of text boxes to be added. I am adding it dynamically by calling a javacript method on the click of a add row button :(

Comment: You don't have to predefine the number of textboxes anywhere. For stimulating your issue i used 5 rows with textboxes. This function will work with any number of rows. Hope I have mentioned it my answer.

Comment: Thank you :) Could you please tell me what is the use of  href="#" here? How  it will trigger the desired jquery code?

Comment: See [What is href=“#” and why is it used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used) for the `href=“#”` details. But here `href` does nothing. It will work without that. See [**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/m6grjat4/4/). I have created all the rows dynamically.

Comment: Consider do a [Upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) or [accept as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), it can be useful to others.

Comment: Understood. Thank You but If I use dynamic value for the property attribute like this property="strExpDate<%=number%>"  or like this property='<%="strExpDate"+number%>'  I get a JSP exception. If I use a static value for the property attribute the exception is gone.

Comment: My mistake, use name instead. Property should be available in your action form.

Comment: For some reason the name of the text is not getting changed; its strExpDate1 for the iterated rows as well; so when I click on the calendar in the first row the calendar is shown but when I click on the calendar image in the other rows; the hyperlink does not show the calendar but just takes the control to the beginning of the page. 
I get an error message in the console:
The value of the property 'show_calendar' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

I must be doing something wrong but I am not able to figure out.  Please advise.

Comment: Hope you need to check your logic iterate tag.

Comment: See the update part again, I used simple logic for increment the value. Now you will get different name values.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number variable into an string and concatenate to the indexId.
Then again cast back to int. It should work