# Scroll animation in vanilla JavaScript works only for navigation links

Tags: javascript, animation, events, dom, recursion

Here is a codepen which demonstrates my problem: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/yaWQwZ

The objective is to have a scrolling animation when the user clicks on the

1. Top navigation links, and
2. `Back to Top` button in the bottom right corner.

I've managed to implement a vanilla JavaScript solution that meets requirement 1 but I'm struggling with requirement 2.

The solution relies on a recursive `scrollTo` function.

As you can see when you scroll down and click on the `My work` link, the animation runs correctly. However when you scroll down and click on the `Back to Top` button there is no animation and the page just jumps to top. I can't figure out why and how to fix it.

Here is the JS code:

```
(function() {


  // ======== SCROLL FUNCTION ======== //
  const scrollTo = (element, to, duration) => {
    if (duration <= 0) {return;}
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(() => {
      element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
      if (element.scrollTop === to) {return;}
      scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
  }


  // ======== TOP NAVIGATION ======== //
  // Save DOM elements that can be scrolled to
  let targetElements = {};
  (function() {
    const myWork = document.getElementById('my-work');
    const contact = document.getElementById('contact');
    targetElements = {
      'my-work': myWork,
      contact: contact
    };
  })();

  // Select links with scroll action
  const scrollElements = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll');

  // Add event listeners to navigation links with scroll action
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(scrollElements, scrollElement => {
    scrollElement.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const targetElement = targetElements[(scrollElement.getAttribute('href').slice(1))];
      scrollTo(document.body, targetElement.offsetTop, 800);
    });
  });


  // ======== BACK TO TOP BUTTON ======== // 
  const backToTopElement = document.getElementsByClassName('back-to-top')[0];
  const backToTopTargetElement = document.getElementById('my-work');

  backToTopElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    scrollTo(document.body, backToTopTargetElement.offsetTop, 800);
  });

})();
```

Here is the HTML (the `Back to Top` button is at the bottom):

```
<!-- ======== NAVIGATION ======== -->
<nav role='navigation'>

  <div id="logo-container">
    <a class="scroll" href="#my-work">SUPER CAT</a>
  </div>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a class="scroll menu-link" href="#my-work">MY WORK</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll menu-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>


<!-- ======== MY WORK ======== -->
<article id="my-work">


  <header>
    <h1>MY WORK</h1>
  </header>


  ...


</article>


<!-- ======== CONTACT ======== -->
<footer id="contact">

  <h2>CONTACT</h2>

  ...

</footer>


<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `#` anchor from the href in your `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGbBXz

Here's a great reference question/answer that should address any further questions about `href="#"` and the `href` property inclusion: [What is href="#" and why is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used)

Summarizing the above post (in regards to question in the comments):

`href="#"` targets the top of the page.

`href` is required ONLY in the event the anchor tag is meant to be a hyperlink.

Comment: removing the href all together produces the same result

Comment: Why was the `#` anchor tag causing the issue? Also, is there any reason to use `"javascript:void(0);"` over just removing the `href`?

Comment: found a solid post (didn't want to reinvent the wheel here) which will hopefully be helpful in answering your further questions - see above edit