# What does request.GET.get mean?

Tags: python, django, http

What does request.GET.get mean? I see something like this in Django

```
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
```

which I think is connected to something like

```
<li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
```

How do they work?

Comment: `request.GET` will hold a dictionary and the `.get('page', 1)` is the call on that dictionary to retrieve the value from that dictionary with key 'page'. If key 'page' does not exist, return 1 instead.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) explains this to very clearly.

Comment: how about href=?page

Comment: read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used). You should hit up some web development and HTML tutorials.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `request` object contains information about the user's request. What data they've sent to the page, where they are coming from, etc.

`request.GET` contains the GET variables. These are what you see in your browser's address bar. The `.get()` method is a method used for dictionaries. What your snippet of code is doing is saying, "Get the value of a GET variable with name 'page', and if it doesn't exist, return 1".

Likewise, you will see `request.POST` used when a user submits a form.

You can read more about GET vs. POST [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: how does href=?page relate to therequest.GET

Comment: If your URL contains `?page` then you've defined a variable called page, but it will have a value of `None`. If you wanted to do view the 3rd page, you would say `?page=3`.

Answer (score 11):

`request.GET` is the dictionary of the `GET` variables in the http request made to your server for example:

```
www.google.com?thisIsAGetVarKey=3&thisIsAnotherOne=hello
```

`request.GET` would be: `{"thisIsAGetVarKey": 3, "thisIsAnotherOne":"hello"}`

Because `request.GET` is a dictionary, it has the method `.get()` which retrieves a value for a key in the dictionary

```
dict_b = {'number': 8, 'alphabet':'A'}
print dict_a['number'] #prints 8
print dict_a.get('alphabet') #prints A

print dict_a['bob'] #throws KeyError
print dict_a.get('bob') #prints None
print dict_a.get('bob', default=8) #prints 8
```

Answer (score 1):

request.GET is the dictionary of the 'GET' variables in the http request made to your server for example:
`www.google.com?thisIsAGetVarKey=3&thisIsAnotherOne=hello`

request.GET would be: `{"thisIsAGetVarKey": 3, "thisIsAnotherOne":"hello"}`

Because request.GET is a dictionary, it has the method .get() which retrieves a value for a key in the dictionary -

```
dict_a = {'age': 3}
print dict_a['age'] #prints 3
print dict_a.get('a') #also prints 3

print dict_a['hello'] #throws KeyError
print dict_a.get('hello') #prints None
print dict_a.get('hello', default=3) #prints 3
```

Comment: so basically the request.GET.get() works like the kwargs