# Search with ajax + django view

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

can u please help me. I want to create search using ajax function and django view. There are input and submit button. When I clicked on submit button, jQuery takes value of input and create ajax request. Its good. But in the view, when i want to print serch_by value in console, there is an output:

`None
qwer asdf zxvc` <- value of input

I think it is a problem. But maybe no. Help me, please.

HTML:

```
<form id="searchform" {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="q" type="text" id="search">
  <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit"></button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function initSearchForm(){
    $('#searchsubmit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        q = $('#search').val();
        updateContentBySearch(q);
  });
}
function updateContentBySearch(q) {
    var data = {};
    data['search_by'] = q
    data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $('#searchform [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search_products/",
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        success:
            $('.product_content').load(url, function() { ...
            }),
        });

    }
```

View:

```
def search_products(request):
     data = request.GET
     search_by = data.get('search_by')
     print(search_by) # The console is displayed first 'None' and at 
                      # the next line value of search_by
if search_by:
    q = Q()
    for tag in search_by.split():
        q |= Q(brand__brand_name__iexact=tag) | Q(model__iexact=tag)
    products = Product.objects.filter(q)

return render(request, 'main/product_content.html', {'products': product})
```

Comment: what does `print(data)`  give you?

Comment: @hansTheFranz `<QueryDict: {}> `   - first line                                                                                                                                                    
`<QueryDict: {'search_by': ['qwer asdf zxcv'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['svfwfyu2sxUmNkI9byPHNuTmYkOKU5LBoDSP8rNsicn7LN5bJKFS9r1LUNdDIvyZ']}>` - second line. But there is no function print anywhere else. I check all views

Comment: you need to lookup how to get values from json formated data. I guess "qwer asdf zxcv" is what you typed into the searchbar? for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598962/what-does-request-get-get-means

Comment: @hansTheFranz yes, its that i typed into searchbar. But in another views, i did same and all was OK

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/search-products/',
        data: {
          'search_by': q
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // do your thing
        }
      });
```

Comment: Delete csrf token from data sending and change data in ajax function to `data: {'search_by': q} ` and change getting data in view to `search_by = request.GET.get('search_by')`. It doesn't help.

Comment: Try passing in the query directly as your data instead of using a dictionary

Comment: Can u tell me how I do it, please? I dont know

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.