# Website jumps to top after adding <tr> to <tbody> with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

i use jquery to add a full  line to an existing table.
Unfortunately the website jumps to the very top after this (as if i would reload it completely).

My code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addParam()">foo</a>
```

And the JS:

```
    function addParam() {
        $('#request_params tbody').append('<tr><td><input class="form-control paramcomplete" type="text" name="input_param_name" size="40" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="input_param_value" size="40"/></td><td> <a href="#" onclick="removeParam(this)"><img src="/SequenceControl/pics/remove.png" style="width:20px" /></a></td></tr>');

        return false;
    }
```

Is there a possibility to make it stay where it is when i clicked on the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `href="#"`. It causes the jump to top

[What is href="#" and why is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used)

Answer (score 3):

also, you can do like `href="javascript:void(0);"`

or you can do like following

```
function addParam(e)
{
    // do your stuff
    e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default action
});
```

Comment: nice, it could also be a solution

Comment: You are missing the `event`  passing in `addParam()` => `addParam(e)`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **href** tag from the HTML. You don't need it!

Comment: Are you sure it will work? For me it doesn't make a link like that.

Comment: I'm sure it works and it doesn't need to be a link to work. He could use any element to do that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel out the default action so use `onclick="return addParam()"`,

However I would recommend you to use correct semantic element; `<button>` instead of `anchor` and also as you are using jQuery use unobtrusive event handler

*HTML*

```
<button class="addRow" type="button" onclick="addParam()">foo</button >
```

*Script*

```
$('.addRow').on('click', function(){
     //Your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned href="#" in anchor tag, which doesn't specify an id name, so clicking an anchor with href="#" will move the scroll position to the top.

remove href attribute from anchor tag.

```
<a onclick="addParam()">foo</a>
```