# Anchor links not working when I used it in include files in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Im using include 'header.php' so i'll not repeat my header code all over again but I noticed it that the links inside the header.php are not working except the parent file the dashboard.php.
ALl the anchor tags inside the dashboard.php are working but not inside the header.php

This is my dashboard.php code

```
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>

<!-- Setting the treeview active -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("treeview1").className = "active menu-open"
</script>
<!-- End Setting the treeview active -->

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Version 2.0</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="manageQuestions.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Question</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<?php require_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Heres the header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>SOG Evaluation System</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/dist/css/skins/skin-green.css">


  <!-- CLOCK rico -->
  <script src="../assets/plugins/clock/ricoClock.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->









</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini skin-green"> <!-- set dito yung name ng theme -->
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="dashboard.php" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>SOG</b></span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg">SOG Evaluation System</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>
      <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
          <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-success">4</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- start message -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="../assets/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Support Team
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end message -->
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="../assets/dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        AdminLTE Design Team
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 hours</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="../assets/dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Developers
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Today</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="../assets/dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Sales Department
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="../assets/dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Reviewers
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 days</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-warning text-yellow"></i> Very long description here that may not fit into the
                      page and may cause design problems
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-red"></i> 5 new members joined
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart text-green"></i> 25 sales made
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-user text-red"></i> You changed your username
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="../assets/dist/img/avatar.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">Superadmin</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="../assets/dist/img/avatar.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                <p>
                  Superadmin - Web Developer
                  <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                </p>
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Body -->
              <li class="user-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Followers</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Sales</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Friends</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->

        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="../assets/dist/img/avatar.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>Superadmin</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
      <!-- <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form> -->


      <!-- /.search form -->

      <div id="clockbox" style="font:12pt ; color:#ffffff;text-align: center;margin-bottom: 7px;padding: 10px"></div>

      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->


      <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>

        <li class="treeview" id="treeview1">
          <a href="dashboard.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="treeview" id="treeview2">
          <a href="manageUsers.php">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>User Management</span>
          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="treeview" id="treeview3">
          <a href="manageQuestions.php">
            <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> <span>Questionnaire Management</span>
          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="treeview" id="treeview4">
          <a href="manageSchedule.php">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>Evaluation Schedule</span>
          </a>

        </li>


        <li class="treeview" id="treeview5">
          <a href="viewResults.php">
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> <span>Evaluation Results</span>
          </a>

        </li>


        <li class="treeview" id="treeview6">
          <a href="generateReports.php">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> <span>Reports</span>
          </a>

        </li>


        <li class="treeview" id="treeview7">
          <a href="manageSystemSettings.php">
            <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> <span>System Settings</span>
          </a>

        </li>
       <li class="header">LABELS</li>
        <li><a href="manageQuestions.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i> <span>Important</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow"></i> <span>Warning</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-aqua"></i> <span>Information</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

Comment: Let me guess. Your links in header are local links. For example "about.php". And when you click on the link you get 404 that "includes/about.php" does not exist?

Comment: You could include your header file here in question too. Since that is where the problem is.

Comment: There's no error showing on my console. It is just not clickable.

Comment: Where do the links go? Click on them what is showing in address bar? Or look at the pop-up field

Comment: i updated the post. even the address bar is not showing up the destination.

Comment: All your links are empty. They are all `<a href="#"`. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used

Comment: It's funny how the two only lines of php are to include other php files and (at least header) doesn't have a single line of php. Why not do it all in html instead?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I already found the error. The conflict is on my class, the treeview class on my sidebar-menu (header.php). I just removed it and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

All your links are empty. They are all `<a href="#"`.
Then above href will make the browser go to top of page.

The way it should be used is `<a href="#about"`.
And that will make the browser go to the about section (if there is an about id)

See this answer for a complete documentation of how it works.

[What is href="#" and why is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used)