# How to make webpage not scroll to the top when data displayed on it changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Sorry for weird title, but couldn't find better explanation.

I have spring webapp, which on one page has content similar to social network. In `angularjs` controller I have an array in which I store posts to be displayed on view. So with `ng-repeat` I am displaying the content of that array in controller. On the bottom of the page I have button that loads more posts (since I don't want all possible posts to be displayed at once), and I append new posts to array, and the list on actual page updates and show loaded posts, but when I click on that button that loads more posts browser scrolls to the top of the page, is there a way to somehow disable that scrolling to the top?

This is the shortened version of my code.

html:

```
    <div class="main" ng-model="activities" ng-repeat="activity in activities">
        <div class="helper" >
        <center>
            <p><img alt="{{activity.user.username}}" ng-src="pictures/{{activity.user.picture}}" height="50px"> </img> </p>
            <p><a href="#" >{{activity.user.username}} </a></p>
            <br />
            <p class="date">{{activity.activity.datum}} </p>
            <p>
            {{activity.activity.tempo}}/km {{activity.activity.distance}} km</p>
            <br />
        </center>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
    <center><a href="#" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</a></center>
</div>
```

js

```
    $scope.loadMore = function(){
        $scope.getActivities(3 , $scope.currentPage+1 , $scope.loggedInUser.username).then(function(response){
            $scope.currentPage++;

            for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++){
                $scope.activities.push(response[i]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Every time `$scope.activities` is changed, that change is shown on the view automatically, but it also scrolls the page to the top.

Comment: Show the code for the button, and the HTML of the page.

Comment: @AlexK I did. 12345

Comment: Tried overflow-y on the parent containers?

Comment: Try replacing anchor's href attribute value to `javascript:void(0)` instead of `#`

Comment: `<a href="#">` [takes you to the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used). You could use a different value, like `href="#!"`, or you could leave off `href` and style the link using CSS.

Comment: @AlexK Thanks a lot, that worked, post that in the answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="#">` takes you to the top of the page. To prevent that behavior from your links, you can do any of the following

- Use `href="#!"` (where `!` is not an `id` of any element on the page)
- Use `href="javascript:void(0)"`
- Omit the `href` attribute completely, and style the link using CSS

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used) for more information.