# How can I put something like *332*18747586# as value in href="" in html?

Tags: php, html

How can I put something like *332*18747586# as value in `href=""` in HTML?
I want to top up and the string we use to top up in our country is something like *332*18747586#

The following is my sample code

```
<?php
   $a="*332*18747586#";
   $aa=(string)$a;
?>

<a href="tel:<?php echo $aa; ?>">Click Here To Top Up</a>
```

But the result is *332*18747586, `href` does not take `#`.
How can I include `#` in my result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`#` has a special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used) in URLs. It is used to denote the fragment of the URL, and you need to escape it to use it in the URL.

Replace `#` with `%23` and it will work.

```html
<a href="tel:*332*18747586%23">Click Here To Top Up</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much piy, you saved my time