# Use a condition on href tag html

Tags: html, href

I have the following code :

```
if (client.id != 0)
{
    var summaryLink = Url.Action("Add", "Client");
    <a href="@summaryLink">
        <div>
            <h3>Client</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
}
else
{
    <a>
        <div class="mdl-tabs__title">
            <h3>Client</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
}
```

This works, but I don't want to repeat the code inside the  tag but add the href on condition.

Any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: Hey is this razor syntax? .net Mvc?

Comment: this is asp.net mvc probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ternary operator? see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) also using a hash won't cause a redirect you could use an empty string or some other alternative [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used)

```
var summaryLink = client.id != 0 ? Url.Action("Add", "Client") : "#";
<a href="@summaryLink">
  <div>
    <h3>Client</h3>
  </div>
</a>
```