# How to click the tab of a URL?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am using VBA to scrape a website. I was given the URL to the homepage of the website, but I need to access the info in its tabs. The URL stays the same upon entering the tab. I have looked online.

```
<li>
<a href="#" onclick="displayQuery();">Query</a>
</li>
```

I looked into HTML and this is the part that is executed when I click on the relevant tab.

I tried `ie.document.querySelector("div[id=overview]").Click`.

Comment: why do you think this selector works? it's not a DVI and doesn't have the ID

Comment: My apologies Philip, I did not use the DIV or ID directly. I was trying to substitute the values but to no avail.

Comment: I realised the mistake was that the code was embedded within a frame. so it should have went something like ie.document.frames(0).querySelector("div[id=overview]").Click. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onclick` attribute. You are after an `a` tag element. Also, as mentioned in comments that id is not shown in the html above (though may belong to another element).

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick='displayQuery();']").click
```

To open in a new tab would require possibly amending this element via javascript.

If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397285/6241235) answer is correct:

> Clicking an anchor with href="#" will move the scroll position to the
>   top.

The real work is happening in the function called by the `onclick` event i.e. `displayQuery();`

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have tried but encountered error "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed".

Comment: though I think I have had this when executing javascript via click that IE doesn't know how to handle/doesn't like.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: the link can only be accessed using intranet. thanks so much QHarr!