# What kind of html link is this?

Tags: html

What kind of HTML link is this? And how does it work?

I've researched in PHP, and it similar code, but href does not include file extension.

`<a href="/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2"> Link </a>`

Comment: You maybe need to check this before posting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used

Comment: https://launchschool.com/books/http/read/what_is_a_url

Comment: There is no extenstion because they are rewriting URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This type of link shows that you are entering a particular directory in the root of the website. Let say you saw this link from a website called me.com then it means you have

```
me.com/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2
```

However `/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2` is a query to the directory on that website.

Answer (score 0):

the domain will be the prefix for this link, after that it will be like it:

```
 www.example.com/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2
```

and `?catID=2` is QueryString that transfer data in url.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question about why there is no file extension at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
?catID=2
```

at the end means ur passing information to the url.

```
?
```

means that ur going to pass on info.

```
catID=2
```

is saying that ur going to pass on catID with a value of 2.

so

```
<a href="/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2"> Link </a>
```

means ur passing on catID with a value of 2 to link:

```
directory/subdirectory/category
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question about why there is no file extension at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

That URL sends you to the index (main) page of the `/directory/subdirectory/category` directory on the root of whatever website the link is on.

For example, on `example.com`, that link would send you to `http://example.com/directory/subdirectory/category/index.html?catID=2`. However, the `/index.html` will not show in the URL bar. The `?catID=2` is a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). There is no extension because the server will automatically send the `index.html` file in the specified directory if there is no specific file requested. (Note: `index.html` is the default. Back-end scripts can change what file gets sent.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, links can be that way. It is a query to the directory on the site you're checking out.

`www.example.com/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2`
Can become

```
<a href="/directory/subdirectory/category?catID=2"> Link </a>
```

on example.com