# Strange behaviour of <a href=”#”>

Tags: html, browser, scroll

I'm using `<a href=”#”>` on more pages to disable scrolling, and it works.

There is one page where I need to use `<a href=”#/”>` to make it work, because the browser is not adding the `/` at the end of the URL.

What's causing this? Why is this happening?

Comment: Hello, I guess that more information is needed for this. What is the distinguishing feature of that page? Does it happen in all browsers? What happens if you don't add the / and click on the link?

Comment: Sadly I can't find any distinguishing features in the code. It's the same in all browsers (MS Edge, Chrome PC/Android, Safari). If I don't add the / it scrolls to the top on click. On the other pages the browser adds automatically the / to the URL when it is clicked.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used Basically href # is expected to scroll to top. The link recommends to use href="#!" as a placeholder on the assumpion that there is no anchor named "!"

Comment: It looks like my question is a duplicate for that post. In my case practically the / works just like the !