# Downloading files using selenium on an element having href = "#"

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, download

```
<span class="download-csv link"><span class="icon icon-download"></span>Download
                <a href="#" class="hide download-link"></a></span>
```

I am trying to click on a link that downloads a CSV file of my equity holdings from the kite zerodha website using selenium, the element to that link is as shown above. It doesn't have a link but a # so when I try to run my code :

```
element = driver.find_element(by = By.LINK_TEXT, value="Download")
element.click()
```

it's not working and giving me lots of errors. The download button looks like this :
[image]

Comment: share the website link, and the link you are trying to download from.

Comment: Hello, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used

Comment: In order to help you we need a link to the page you are working on or at least the XML of it, as a text, not picture + all your code, not just a command you shared + errors you are getting.

Comment: I can't share the website link, it's my Demat account in Zerodha, I want to automate daily downloads of the CSV with my daily equity holdings and keep a track of it in my local machine.